# I am trying to make the navigation like the code above

Tags: jquery, html, menu, navigation

```
<li><a href="/shop/shopbrand.html?xcode=071&mcode=008&type=Y">top</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop/shopbrand.html?xcode=071&mcode=005&type=Y">top2</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop/shopbrand.html?xcode=071&mcode=003&type=Y">top3</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop/shopbrand.html?xcode=071&mcode=001&type=Y">top4</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop/shopbrand.html?xcode=071&mcode=010&type=Y">top5</a></li>
```

I am trying to make the navigation like the code above.

I want to add class `ACTIVE` on the menu using JQUERY.

In the case as above, link addresses are all same but REF is different, how can I write the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options to select one of those items: by ID or by position.

**By ID**

You first have to give a different ID to each of your `<li>`, like

```
<li id="li_1"><a href="/shop/shopbrand.html?xcode=071&mcode=008&type=Y">top</a></li>
<li id="li_2"><a href="/shop/shopbrand.html?xcode=071&mcode=005&type=Y">top2</a></li>
<li id="li_3"><a href="/shop/shopbrand.html?xcode=071&mcode=003&type=Y">top3</a></li>
<li id="li_4"><a href="/shop/shopbrand.html?xcode=071&mcode=001&type=Y">top4</a></li>
<li id="li_5"><a href="/shop/shopbrand.html?xcode=071&mcode=010&type=Y">top5</a></li>
```

Then you can add the class to one of them with `$("#li_n").addClass("active");`

**By position**

You add the class to the `<li>` in the desired position with `$("li:eq(n)").addClass("active");`